# File not creating in ANDROID using FileOutputStream Class

Tags: java, android, android-file

When the button is clicked a file should be created. But in my code file is not being created.

```
bcheck.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            p=1;//app installed
            try {
                FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("abc.txt");
                String s = "Installed";
                byte b[]=s.getBytes();
                fout.write(s.getBytes());
                fout.close();
                System.out.println("FILE CREATED");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println("FILE NOT CREATED");
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: where do you want to create your file !

Comment: FileOutputStream does not create a file, it opens a stream to write into a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("abc.txt");
```

That will not work on Android. Always use a method to get at a valid directory for which you can read and write.

For example, this would work:

```
FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(new File(getFilesDir(), "abc.txt"));
```

(assuming that this line is in a method in some subclass of `Context`, like an `Activity` or `Service`)

`getFilesDir()` returns to you a directory in [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html). You can also use [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html), if you prefer, though that can get more complicated due to permissions and such.